# Setup Visual Studio 2005 to print line numbers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, line-numbers

How can I get line numbers to `print` in **Visual Studio 2005** when printing `code` listings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option in the Print Dialog to do the same (in VS 2005 and 2008 atleast)!

Answer (score 7):

Isn't there an option in the Print Dialog?

Edit: There is. Go to File => Print, and then in the bottom left there is "Print what" and then "Include line Numbers"